# Overriding the PostBuildEvent in TFSBuild.proj

Tags: tfs

I'm using currently VS 2010 and TFS 2008. In one of our solutions we have a .csproj file with the following:

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">


<TransformXml Source="..\..\..\ProjectX\ProjectXWebSite\ProjectXWebSite\Web.config" Transform="..\..\..\ProjectX\ProjectXWebSite\ProjectXWebSite\Web.$(Configuration).config" Destination="..\..\..\ProjectX\ProjectXWebSite\ProjectXWebSite\Web.$(Configuration).config.transformed" />

</Target>

<PropertyGroup>
<PostBuildEvent>xcopy "C:\Source\Projects\ProjectX\ProjectXWebSite\ProjectXWebSite\Web.$(Configuration).config.transformed" "C:\Source\Projects\ProjectX\ProjectXWebSite\ProjectXWebSite\Web.config" /R /Y</PostBuildEvent>
 </PropertyGroup>
```

This works fine when building locally, but TFS is failing when it reaches `<PostBuildEvent>`, because this path is not available on the build machine. How can I get TFS to either skip the entire "BeforeBuild" or just set the `<PostBuildEvent>` to an empty string, so that the build will work successfully when built locally in VS2010 and via TFS 2008? I've tried within TFSBuild.proj to set `<Target Name="BeforeBuild" />`, but this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend against using absolute pathnames in your projects - relative paths will make them relocatable and headaches like this will disappear.

i.e. In the post-build xcopy, just change `C:\Source\Projects\ProjectX` to `..\..\..\ProjectX`

(You can't rely on always being able to put your code on C: - I've had to move my code from C: to D: or E: due to lack of disk space or installation of a new drive on several occasions, and using relative paths has made this process very easy. It's also very handy at times to be able to have multiple copies (different versions or branches) of your source code on your PC at once and still be able to build them all)

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jason and sorry about the late response. I had tried that previously; however, when I make it relative I can not build the solution successfully locally nor via TFS. I get the following error:                                                                                                                                  The command "xcopy "..\..\..\ProjectX\ProjectXWebSite\ProjectXWebSite\Web.Test.config.transformed" "..\..\..\ProjectX\ProjectXWebSite\ProjectXWebSite\Web.config" /R /Y" exited with code 4.

Comment: Code 4 probably means your paths are wrong. They should be relative to the location of the solution (.sln) file so if the file is in the same solution, they should probably just be something like `"ProjectXWebSite\Web.Test.config.transformed"` or `"Web.Test.config.transformed"`. Just open a file explorer on the folder containing the .sln, and navigate to the source/destination folder. If you go up to a parent folder, add "..\" and if you go down into a child folder, add it's name: "Child\" and you should build the correct path.

Comment: ... xcopy can also be a bit fickle - it should work well if the paths are correct, but for a single file you can use "copy", which is much simpler to get right and more informative if it fails, or if you're on Vista/Win7/Server2008, "robocopy" is also built in to the OS.

Comment: (You can also open a command prompt in the folder containing the .sln and then type in the xcopy command manually to try different relative paths until you work out the exact paths that are needed)